# How to add Oracle Column comment in Japanese?

Tags: oracle, comments

I'm trying to add comment in Table Column in Oracle, but they don't display in Japanese as what I've typed. (Just ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿(¿¿¿')

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you make sure that your different system components are set to use UTF-8?

Comment: What is your column's data type ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the NLS_LANG envirment variable both for the program you add the comments with as the one to show the comments with correctly.

eg. if you start from a windows command prompt:

```
SET NLS_LANG=JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJIS
```

And in SQL Developer (if you use this to look at comments) go to Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS And adjust accordingly.